# Auto select an option from select when the options are received using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

My problems is that I have a drop down list and its values populated with Ajax from a jQuery call. How can I make a specific option set as the default selected option?

## html

```
<li>
     <label>Type</label>
     <select  name="type"class="TypeSelector"></select>
     <span class="errorMessage"></span>
</li>
```

## jQuery

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/Type/getAllTypes/TRUE",function(data){
            var options = '';
            options+="<option>Select Type</option>";
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                options += "<option>"+data[i]+"</option>";
            }
            if($("#addPlace #apTypeSelect").length){
                $("#addPlace #apTypeSelect").html(options);
            }
            if($('.TypeSelector').length){
                $('.TypeSelector').html(options);
            }
        });
```

and the options selected is

```
<?php echo $question['name'];?>
```

I tried like this:

```
<li>
         <label>Type</label>
         <select  value="<?php echo $question['name'];?>"name="type"class="TypeSelector"></select>
         <span class="errorMessage"></span>
</li>
```

...but doesn't work
what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it via jQuery. Give your `select` an ID (I've used `mySelect`) and do:

```
$(function() {
    $("#mySelect").val("<?php echo $question['name'];?>");
});
```

Comment: i did this in the if statement `$('.TypeSelector').val('<?php echo $questionInfo["name"]; ?>');` but doesn't work

Comment: no, no error is thrown , and i tried to echo `<?php echo $questionInfo["name"]; ?>` and it gives me the right value

Comment: @tottiroma Ah sorry, check my updated edit. I was using single quotes twice, probably an escaping issue.

Comment: @tottiroma Just to clarify, does the echo value match one of the **values** of your options?

Comment: yes for sure , and i have just echo its values and it works good and match one of the options in the drop down list

Comment: And that matches the `value=` for one of the options yeah? Out of interest, try hard coding the `.val(` to the value of the first option in the list?

Comment: oh i have just got you , please look at my jquery i think the options doesn't have values , right ?  i think i have to put this in the for loop `ptions += "<option value="+data[i]+">"+data[i]+"</option>";`

Comment: @tottiroma ahhh yes! Add the `value` attribute to all of your options in your jquery :)

Comment: i changed the `options` on my for loop to this `options += "<option value="+data[i]+">"+data[i]+"</option>";` but doesn't work :( , am i getting wrong on coding ?

Comment: oh there is one thing, my jquery is not on the same page with html , it is on another file ,

Comment: Try `options += "<option value='"+data[i]+"'>"+data[i]+"</option>";`

Comment: still doesn't work , but i told you that my jQuery function is not on the same page with my html code and $question cames from html page , not from JS page , so i thing that jquery function doesn't see $question , right ?

Comment: @tottiroma Sorry yeah I missed that, you might want to call a function in your JS file from the HTML page and pass the $question in, that way you can use it in the file :)

Comment: @tottiroma No problems! Glad I could help :)